# Increase all product prices by a percentage including variations in Woocommerce

Tags: sql, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

With woocommerce I would like to update all my prices by a percentage. A lot of my products are variable (with multiple variations) so I need every price on the site to increase, not just simple products.

I have tried a number of sql queries but they only set the price to 0 and dont affect the variation prices.

Im using the latest versions of Wordpress and Woocommerce.

Any help would be great.

Comment: You can use a plugin for that: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-bulk-percentage-pricing/

Comment: this plugin doesnt support updating the variations. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update** *(updated the sale product query)*

You should need 4 SQL queries:

- To update the active price
- To update the regular price
- To update the sale price ***(updated)***
- To delete the cached variation prices

The updated prices are rounded with 2 decimal digits precision.

You can run that four at the same time, but **make a database backup before**. Also check that the suffix of your database is `wp_` and if not replace by your tables suffix.

The 4 SQL queries *(replace **`1.25`** by your corresponding rate percentage)*:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
SET meta_value = ROUND(meta_value * 1.25, 2)
WHERE meta_key = '_price';

UPDATE wp_postmeta
SET meta_value = ROUND(meta_value * 1.25, 2)
WHERE meta_key = '_regular_price';

UPDATE wp_postmeta
SET meta_value = ROUND(meta_value * 1.25, 2)
WHERE meta_key = '_sale_price' AND meta_value != '';

DELETE FROM `wp_options`
WHERE (`option_name` LIKE '_transient_wc_var_prices_%'
OR `option_name` LIKE '_transient_timeout_wc_var_prices_%');
```

**Tested and works** for all product types **include product variation post type**.

Comment: Hi thanks for this. It updates the prices but makes the variable pricing look like this.

http://prntscr.com/it0kyf